# Several Select: disable/hide/remove selected option in one select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to create a form with several select and the user should rank these selects from 1-8. However, I'm having some trouble hiding/removing/disabling the select option.

**Here's my form**
this is just the first four of the 8 selects to be ranked

```
  <label>Spirituality</label>\
 <select id="ranks1" class="form-control form-input" name="answer[]" required>
    <option value="" selected>--</option>
    <?php for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"><?= $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
   <label>School</label>
  <select id="ranks1" class="form-control form-input" name="answer[]" required>
    <option value="" selected>--</option>
    <?php for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"><?= $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
   <label>Family</label>
  <select id="ranks1" class="form-control form-input" name="answer[]" required>
    <option value="" selected>--</option>
    <?php for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"><?= $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
   <label>Friends</label>
  <select id="ranks1" class="form-control form-input" name="answer[]" required>
    <option value="" selected>--</option>
    <?php for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){?>
    <option value="<?=$i;?>"><?= $i;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

**This is what I got so far for my script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ranks1").click(function () {
        $('#ranks1 option').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

And I did this for the CSS. For the disabled option

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**More background on what the form looks like.**
[image: More background on what the form looks like.]

Comment: A set of selects doesn't make a good UI for rank-order. Consider instead [something like this](https://www.checkbox.com/docs/documentation/survey-creation-settings/rank-order-item-guide/)

Comment: When do you want to disable the select option?  In other words, what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: You know that `id` is a unique identifier and you should not have elements with same `id` in your DOM. Right?!

Comment: @user1477388 .the number that has been selected in the select option is not hiding/disabling

Comment: @EhsanT ohh. I just thought that they're on the same form group and should have the same ids. sorry

Comment: @geek_10101010 I think you want the `change` event, not the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wanting the `change` event, not the `click` event.

Please consider the following example which disables the selected option on change.

HTML:

```
<select id="selectlist">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#selectlist').on('change', function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  if (selectedVal != 0) {
    // disable selected value
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option[value=' + selectedVal + ']');
    selectedOption.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tp9urjkb/

Comment: However I have multiple selects.

Comment: The same principal would apply to all.  For example, see https://jsfiddle.net/tp9urjkb/1/

Comment: [![my goal is to disable the selected option in the next select not on the same select][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rgtk.png

Comment: To disable the selected option in the next selectlist, you can simply use jquery's `.next()` function like so https://jsfiddle.net/tp9urjkb/2/